# Is there a way to send users to the push notification section in Settings via a button action?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Is there a way to send users to the push notification section of my app in Settings via a button action within my own app?

Comment: If this was doable, there would be a URL scheme that supported it. None, exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: no.

While you could open the general settings via `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)`, there is currently no way to programmatically navigate to the app's settings page.

Comment: Any way the users can change notification settings within my own app?

Comment: No. Of course you could offer them similar options (sound, badge) that you adhere to (server side) when sending notifications, but these won't change the system settings.